# How to make a custom input range slider

Tags: html, css, input, slider, range

I want to create a custom slider like shown in the image. How can I do this? Please see the fiddle which I have linked so that you can see what I have already tried.

[image]

```html
<h2>working slider input range</h2>
<input class="slider-info" name="gdskill[1]" id="gdskill1" type="range" min="0" value="0" max="10" step="1" list="ticks" oninput="Output1.value = gdskill1.value" />
<output id="Output1">0</output>


<input name="gdskill[2]" id="gdskill2" type="range" min="0" value="0" max="10" step="1" list="ticks" oninput="Output2.value = gdskill2.value" />
<output id="Output2">0</output>

<datalist id="ticks">
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>10</option>
</datalist>


<h2>I want a design like the one shown in the image above. Is this possible? Can anyone help me with it as I am a little new to CSS.</h2>
```

Fiddle link:   https://jsfiddle.net/9qgx71kd/2/

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/

Comment: @fix can you please give a working demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the best I could do in short notice, though you'll want to test across IE and Firefox. This will probably require some tweaking but should be a good start.

https://jsfiddle.net/9qgx71kd/3/

****HTML****

```
<input name="gdskill[1]" id="gdskill1" type="range" min="0" value="0" max="10" step="1" list="ticks" oninput="Output1.value = gdskill1.value" /><br />
<output id="Output1" class="output">0</output>

<div>
<input name="gdskill[2]" id="gdskill2" type="range" min="0" value="0" max="10" step="1" list="ticks" oninput="Output2.value = gdskill2.value" /><br />
<output id="Output2" class="output">0</output>
</div>

<datalist id="ticks">
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>10</option>
</datalist>
```

****CSS****

```
.output {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 50%;
}

input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none; /* Hides the slider so that custom slider can be made */
  height:5px;
  width:100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #07C;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 2px solid #07C;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 0px; /* You need to specify a margin in Chrome, but in Firefox and IE it is automatic */
}

input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

If you want to add a shadow to the thumb-slider you can add `box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);` to the `input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb` block

Comment: Didn't account for browsers other than Chrome and it doesn't exacly match the requested image. Slider-bar only fills in up to selected tic in the example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a javascript library that replace the input element with easy styling elements for example JCF. See their [demo page.](https://www.psd2html.com/js-custom-forms/)